# What's wrong with the Big Spin Model?

Tags: cosmology, galaxies, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect, galaxy-rotation-curve

A Dr. Serkan Zorba [has a paper on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.3021) in which he considers, what if the universe is actually slowly rotating? This gives rise to centrifugal and Coriolis forces on a galactic scale that seem to *perfectly* explain the effects of dark energy and dark matter. Not only that, but it explains a few other observations in cosmology.

But I haven't been able to find anyone else commenting on his model, and it's been several years now. Is there something wrong with it that allows us to dismiss it out of hand? Or do other cosmologists just not care?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfesXDG848c

Comment: This is a video of his. He explains what he did in the paper and says that his paper was rejected somewhere giving a reason that his "model concludes that the universe is anisotropic but the universe, as we know, is isotropic". Maybe this is the reason people ignore or don't talk much about his paper. Anyway, the table of data is really close to the data predicted by the current model which I find to be fascinating.

Comment: @シャシュワト Thanks! It bugs me that it was rejected simply for that reason because he gives a falsifying test for the model.

Comment: I am no expert but the Hubble's constant and angular velocity do have the same units (that is the reason when multiplied by time $(t)$ they then can be exponentiated as $e^{\omega t}$ and $e^{H t}$ as $H t$ and $\omega t$ are dimensionless). Radians are dimensionless units. Are there no other noticeable flaws?

Comment: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-RZE4TVESbDQ/VzY4bVAN46I/AAAAAAAABFg/uN2eCiimJsA1_TmpvvYlVjA__IWEeCIkACLcB/s1600/GamowsUniverse.png

Comment: George Gamow speculated about rotating universe accounted by relativity in 1946. Check the link above.

Comment: Hello! I think the problem with the rotation of the universe is that the universe now has a special direction. Centrifugal force only acts perpendicularly to this special direction. We would see galaxies going racing apart only in radially outward direction but see galaxies moving outward in all directions. Hence this is what makes it wrong I guess. But its really easy to spot this mistake I don't know how he came to this supposedly wrong conclusion.

Comment: @シャシュワト From our perspective, we would still see every galaxy receding because they don't have the same velocity as us. The ones further from the cosmic axis recede faster, and we recede faster than the ones closer to the axis.

Comment: But wouldn't the spin make the expansion planar, which it clearly isn't? Kind of like rotating cylinder is what his paper assumes but we live in a spherically symmetrical universe. Hubble constant then, would be a variable depending of the vertical angle coordinate (can't recall name, the one other than azimuthal angle).  Correct if wrong.

Comment: @シャシュワト Ah I understand now. I suppose that is a problem. Perhaps I could email him with these questions...

Comment: It's not a good sign when a paper is written without using LaTeX.  This PDF only and bad formatings cannot help the author, and may even be a clue that the paper is just crackpot physics.  Personaly, I'm not even motivated to read this paper because of the ugly format.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't seem to have been presented or published anywhere other than as a somewhat casual/informal document on the arXiv, which probably helps explain why it's been ignored.

Well, that and the fact that it's ignorant of all the relevant research and is very, very wrong.

Since I'm not really a GR person, I'll pass over the first ("explains dark energy") part, though I suspect it's got serious problems.

The second part of the paper attempts to explain "dark matter" effects -- i.e., the rotation curves of galaxies (he doesn't seem aware of the role postulated dark matter plays in explaining galaxy group and cluster dynamics, or the overall energy density of the universe) -- with the Coriolis force. This requires that disk galaxies be oriented so that their angular momentum vectors are parallel to the axis of universal rotation. But for galaxies oriented perpendicular to that direction, the Coriolis effect vanishes. Since real galaxies are randomly oriented, this effect would have been obvious back in the 1970s, when people like Vera Rubin were measuring outer rotation curves of galaxies and finding evidence for dark matter. All disk galaxies show roughly the same dark matter effects, regardless of their orientation.

Put another way, in order for this model to explain dark matter, all disk galaxies would have to have the *same* orientation in 3D space. So all the galaxies we observe would have the same position angle on the sky, with all galaxies near the Galactic plane seen edge-on and all galaxies near the Galactic poles seen face-on. Needless to say, this is not our universe.

The real killer is that the whole model requires the universe to be uniformly rotating with an angular speed approximately equal to the Hubble constant $H_{0}$. But a rotating universe would produce distortions in the cosmic background radiation, as pointed out by [Stephen Hawking back in 1969](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1969MNRAS.142..129H). This was the first in a series of papers attempting to measure, or put upper limits, on the vorticity of the universe. This is usually parameterized as the ratio of the vorticity $\omega$ to the Hubble constant: $\omega / H_{0}$ (note that Zorba uses "$\omega$" for the angular speed). Since the [vorticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity) of a uniformly rotating system is just twice its angular speed, Zorba's model is $\omega/H_{0} \approx 2$. Hawking was able to derive crude upper limits of $\omega / H_{0} < 10^{-3}$, meaning that Zorba's preferred value would be about a thousand times too large. [Barrow et al. (1985)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1985MNRAS.213..917B), using updated data and a more detailed analysis, found an upper limit of $\omega / H_{0} < 2 \times 10^{-5}$.

Studies since then have pushed the upper limit further down. The most recent attempt is probably [this paper in *Physical Review Letters* by Saadeh et al. (2016)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016PhRvL.117m1302S),  which uses both temperature and polarization data from the *Planck* satellite and finds $\omega / H_{0} < 4.7 \times 10^{-11}$.

In other words, *if* the universe is rotating, it's doing so *about a trillion times more slowly* than what Zorba's model assumes.

Comment: do you have a link for a measured "Since real galaxies are randomly oriented" my impression is that the "axis of evil" says that they are not? also your quotes about the equality of the omega with the hubble constant talk of a rotating universe alone in the cosmos, whereas the spin model has it as an item in a bigger set, rotating outside the in an overuniverse, as far as I understand.

Comment: The "axis of evil" is a supposed (and disputed) anisotropy in the cosmic microwave background, allegedly aligned with the *plane of the Solar System*; it has nothing to do with the alignments of galaxies. 

The uniformity of orientation required by Zorba's model means, for example, that every galaxy seen in projection near the plane of the Milky Way would be edge-on, and that every galaxy near the north or south Galactic poles would be face-on. This is basic astronomy, something that would have been obvious to 19th Century observers looking at "spiral nebulae".

Comment: The link below is to a page on the Vigo Cluster, the nearest cluster of galaxies, which spans only a couple of degrees on the sky. It's at a Galactic latitude of about 77 degrees, which means -- in Zorba's model -- all the galaxies should be close to face-on (with inclinations around 13 degrees, where 0 deg is face-on and 90 deg is edge-on). As you can see, there's a wide range of orientations, with some galaxies close to face-on and others very close to edge-on.
http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com/galgrps/vir.html

Comment: This uses a three dimensional model within the universe whereas the whole universe is supposed to be rotating ,carrying all these inside it.  The earth is rotating about itself, and it is also rotating about the sun. these are two different rotations. The motion imparted from the rotation about itself gives Coriolis and what is happening vectorially is different in different latitudes and longitudes. The rotaition about the sun has a different omega and a much smaller effect on the motion of the earth. That part will be correlated with the ecliptic.

Comment: "the spin model has it as an item in a bigger set, rotating outside the in an overuniverse" -- the supposed "bigger set" plays no role in Zorba's model; he's assuming the entire observable universe is well inside his (arbitrary, unmotivated) "disk-shaped model", and his GR discussion assumes a uniformly rotating universe, full stop.

Comment: well, as I read it, that is the whole point, otherwise  the hubble constant  and the limits of rotation of the universe of the big bang model exclude it. IMO, he assumes our universe is a small part of a rotating outside multiverse or some such.  Anyway, we know where we disgagree.

Comment: @Peter Erwin Thanks for the reply. "All disk galaxies show roughly the same dark matter effects, regardless of their orientation." Where can I read more about this? Is there a study eliminating the effects of angular dependence? Zorba does consider the fact that galaxies can have different orientations, and the average apparently agrees with other models. One thing he doesn't address is, given the non-uniform nature of the Coriolis force, we should be able to point to the direction of the cosmic axis by measuring the rotation speed at different points. Maybe that's a flaw if we don't see it.

Comment: I don't think your second criticism is accurate. Those papers are about *vorticity*, which is not a feature of the Zorba model, since everything in our observable universe would be moving in just about the same direction with respect to the cosmic axis, no?

Comment: @HiddenBabel -- "Zorba does consider the fact that galaxies can have different orientations" -- no, he does not. He *does* consider exactly what you say he doesn't, and even touts this as a specific observational prediction -- and then he alludes to "different orientations" as one of the things making individual observations more difficult, and decides to just compute the "average", which uses the Coriolis equation for the perfectly parallel model he started with, which assumes all galaxies have the same ideal orientation.

Comment: @HiddenBabel -- re vorticity: with uniform rotation (as in Zorba's model), the vorticity is the same everywhere and is $= 2 \times \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the angular velocity of rotation. It's only a factor of two different from what I talked about; I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the paper ( not the formulae, as I cannot catch errors if they are there).

> Is there something wrong with it that allows us to dismiss it out of hand? Or do other cosmologists just not care?

It is unfortunate that the paper has not been published if there are no algebraic/computational errors because somebody would have come out with a reasonable defense of the Big Bang standard model against this new proposition. I hope somebody good in cosmological models reads it here and enlightens us. To me it sounds as an intriguing model which does not require modifications of General relativity and seems to be able to model existing observations, including giving a reason [for the axis of evil .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_of_evil_(cosmology))

Actually this last, if I understand it correctly, gives a prediction also, that on average all planetary systems should on average be in the same plane of rotation as our sun system.

One has to accept that there are fashions in physics, and as physicists are also people, sociological behaviors dominate too. The fashion now is the Big Bang, and particles for dark matter. In particle physics, having lived through the emergence of QCD over Feynman's parton model, and the difficulties of getting it universally accepted, I am not surprised that this is not discussed even at the level [of Mond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics).

I hope, if there is nothing computationally wrong or falsified directly by existing observations, this will get more attention.

Comment: I must admit I found this paper while looking for alternatives to dark matter/energy, because I don't like how those are too contrived. Modified gravity doesn't sound any better, but I can believe a rotating universe until someone tells me it's seriously flawed :) .

Comment: Papers are not ignored just because of "fashion". There are tons of papers about dark matter every day that don't follow the WIMP paradigm, the ones that are ignored are ignored because they're bad. In this case, this paper's model makes several blatantly wrong predictions. (It only works for things rotating in one plane, and rotation effects of this magnitude have been ruled out for decades.)

Comment: @HiddenBabel I get what you're going for, but if you focus on looking at "alternative" models that aren't getting attention, you're going to get stuck in a morass of individuals' pet theories that claim to explain everything and actually explain nothing. This guy even claims his model explains inflation and quantum gravity in addition to everything else. There are literally thousands of such people, greatly outnumbering the people who actually know what they're doing. They're a dime a dozen.

Comment: @knzhoufrom from what I understand the universe in this model  is not rotating within itself, i.e. the omega of the paper is not an omega of a rotating universe about some axis going through it. It is an omega around a hypothetical "overuniverse" the axis outside ours.

Comment: @knzhou Also I think that arxiv has a check on such gross errors before it allows the publication on the site.

Comment: @annav There is no check, if you have ever been approved to post (e.g. by having a single person vouch for you) then you can post whatever you want.

Comment: @annav -- The arXiv does not, in general, have a "check on such gross errors".  (They have automated checks for possible plagiarism.) And the discussion in Part II explicitly includes a distance *R* to the rotation axis of the universe -- otherwise the centrifugal and Coriolis equations make no sense.

Comment: In the beginning he states "The rotation of the spacetime of our universe implies that there is extraneous physics, i.e., our
universe is not a closed system, and 
that there 
is a larger universe or
cosmically parallel 
universe.And the implied cosmic axis of the model must have had axial precession (see 
Fig. 
1). The resulting overall u
niverse would be disk
-
shaped, but i
f 
the size of 
our observable 
un
iverse is only a fraction of the
overall, 
(s)

Comment: The axis is outside our obsrvable universe. fig 1

Comment: @annav -- The stuff about "extraneous physics" and "cosmically parallel universe" (and that the universe is "disk-shaped" and "must have had axial precession") is meaningless verbiage. Nothing in his mathematical derivations depends on any of that.

Comment: except that the position of the axis is outside of the observable universe which allows him to use the equality of the hubble constant to the omega of the rotation. Othewise as you observe effects of this magnitude have been observationally ruled ou, .for an observable universe rotating around itself. I am not a fan of the model. I am just trying to clear up the context.

Comment: @annav -- See my updated answer. In a uniformly rotating system, the vorticity is the *same everywhere*, so it doesn't matter where the axis of rotation is.

Comment: @PeterErwin well, I do not plan to sit down and check formulae to undestand why an axis not passing through the center of a universe does not generate   different  effects from one passing through it. lets leave it at that. For fun, here is a published model where it is space time that is rotating http://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/html/10.11648.j.ajaa.20160404.11.html . it addresses the axis of evil too.